# Run autostart program in a terminal instead of having it run hidden in background

Tags: debian, boot, lxde

I have added to `sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart`

the line:

`python /path/to/script.py`

This launches `script.py` on boot.  Which is what I want.  However, I can't see the output from `script.py` about what it is doing.  Autostart just runs it in the background.  How can I get `script.py` to run in a terminal?

I'm using debian.

Comment: run xterm -e python /path/to/script or check `~/.xsession-errors` to see the output

Comment: when I put `xterm -e python /path/to/script` in the autostart file, I get `XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"`

Comment: does this mean I need to install `xterm`?  If so, is there another possible way to do this without installing it?

Comment: If you want to run it in a terminal you need to have a terminal installed. You can choose any terminal you like but it must support specifying the command to execute

Comment: awesome.  That worked.  If you put it in the answer area, I can mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should see the output from your program in `~/.xsession-errors`. If you want to run the command in a terminal itself you have to install a terminal which allows you to specify the command to be executed (most of them should support it), i.e. for xterm you can run:

```
xterm -e python /path/to/script
```

and place it in your autostart file.